# One-liner to find corresponding value in large dataframe r

Tags: r

I am looking for a simple one-liner that will help me find a corresponding value in a dataframe.

Data sample:

```
weather <-data.frame("date" = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by ="days", length.out = 10), temp = runif(10))
weather
         date       temp
1  2000-01-01 0.08520875
2  2000-01-02 0.69003449
3  2000-01-03 0.85892903
4  2000-01-04 0.37790250
5  2000-01-05 0.04121786
6  2000-01-06 0.31550816
7  2000-01-07 0.86219597
8  2000-01-08 0.30844555
9  2000-01-09 0.96949855
10 2000-01-10 0.18851018
```

Lets say I now want to find the day on which the maximum temperature occurred:

```
max_temp <- max(weather$temp)
max_temp
[1] 0.9694985
```

Now there are a couple of ways that I can find the date of this temperature (i.e. the corresponding value that i am after):

```
weather[which(weather$temp == max_temp), which(colnames(weather) == "date")]
[1] "2000-01-09"
```

But this is kind of laborious. I could also use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(weather, temp == max_temp) %>%
   select(date)
        date
1 2000-01-09
```

But again, a two liner in the console just to get this seems like overkill.

I can't help but feel that there must be something like:

```
function(df, name_of_known_variable, value_of_known_variable, character_vector_of_variables_of_interest)
```

So for this example this would look like (assuming the function is "correspond"):

```
correspond(weather, temp, max_temp, date)
1 2000-01-09
```

I have looked all over and can't seem to find something simple for this. Please note that i understand that i could use:

```
weather[which.max(weather$temp), 1]
[1] "2000-01-09"
```

But lets assume that I am not necessarily looking for the maximum temperature (lets imagine i just have a value of interest and i am trying to find the corresponding value). Lets also imagine i have a massive data frame with lots and lots of columns (so many as to make counting them laborious). Further, lets imagine that i want to return corresponding values from multiple columns.

Comment: `weather[ weather$temp == max( weather$temp ), "date"  ]` as a starter, here you can combine flexibly.

Comment: Great, thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: ...and if you want more columns, output by name rather than counting, you can use `weather[ weather$temp == max( weather$temp ), c( "temp, "date" )  ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, using **Base R** only:

Create data, adding two more columns to provide a broader perspective:

```
set.seed( 1110 )
weather <-data.frame( "date" = seq( as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "days", length.out = 10),
    temp = round( runif( 10 ), 2 ),
    loc = round( runif( 10 ) * 10, 2 ),
    speed = round( runif( 10 ) * 50, 1 ) )
> weather
         date temp  loc speed
1  2000-01-01 0.48 9.79  18.9
2  2000-01-02 0.79 9.20  18.6
3  2000-01-03 0.88 9.65  46.3
4  2000-01-04 0.58 0.59   5.3
5  2000-01-05 0.22 6.12  38.7
6  2000-01-06 0.09 3.05  42.6
7  2000-01-07 0.49 4.09   2.1
8  2000-01-08 0.99 8.60  31.9
9  2000-01-09 0.56 4.27  12.6
10 2000-01-10 0.36 6.02  42.7
```

Now we can select per one-liner and based on column names rather than numbers, as required:

```
# The day with the maximum temparature
weather[ weather$temp == max( weather$temp ), "date" ]
[1] "2000-01-08"
```

But we can do a lot more:

```
# Speed and Location (order reversed) on the day with a temperature of 0.49
weather[ weather$temp == .49, c( "speed", "loc" ) ]
  speed  loc
7   2.1 4.09

# Date and speed, based upon two selection criteria (Temparature or Location)
# here we need to use which() to get the row indices
weather[ c( which( weather$temp == min( weather$temp ) ), which( weather$loc == 6.12 ) ), c( "date", "speed" ) ]  
        date speed
6 2000-01-06  42.6
5 2000-01-05  38.7
```

Answer (score 0):

use data.table package. Syntax is simple.

```
a[variable == value_you_want]
a[variable == max(variable]
a[variable == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::slice` is also a possibility here:

```
set.seed(1)
weather <-data.frame("date" = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by ="days", length.out = 10), temp = runif(10))

library(dplyr)
weather %>% arrange(desc(temp)) %>% slice(1)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
        date      temp
      <date>     <dbl>
1 2000-01-07 0.9446753
```

And you can use `dplyr::filter` if you need to look for a specific value